# How to access files from Win partition?

Tags: partition, windows, pop-os

I asked this on https://askubuntu.com/ but they proposed I asked this here instead,

I recently switched from Windows 10 to POP OS.

My disk under Win 10 was partitioned to C and D drive. Is it possible to access the D drive after installing Linux on C drive?

EDIT:

This is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       4096   1023998   1019903   498M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1024000   9412606   8388607     4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3    9412608 226048942 216636335 103.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  226048944 234437550   8388607     4G Linux swap
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to the question? Probably `sudo mkdir /d;sudo mount /dev/sda2 /d` will do the job.

Comment: theoretically, you can access whole your disk in linux. but the partitioning is completely different from windows. Please provide `sudo fdisk -l` in the question.

Comment: If you did not erase the D: "drive" partition as part of install, you can use the NTFS partition. But Windows may have left it with fast start up on or hibernation. Then you can only mount read only. And if no Windows best not to use NTFS as it needs maintenance like chkdsk & defrag that you can only run from Windows or a Windows repair disk. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://superuser.com/questions/1231582/hdd-with-windows-boot-locked-because-of-hibernation-flag

Comment: @icarus I tried `sudo mkdir /d;sudo mount /dev/sda2 /d` but after trying to cd to /d id get permission denied.

Comment: OK, try `sudo umount /d; sudo chmod 0755 /d ; sudo mount /dev/sda2 /s` to change the permissions. However having seen the fdisk output there doesn't seem to be much of `d`, only 4GB or less than 4% of the total space.